# Serving CSS via dropbox suddenly stopped working

Tags: cors, dropbox, cdn, mime, cross-origin-read-blocking

We have been using Dropbox for serving stylesheets to our custom web solutions. This has been working for years now.

We use it like this in the `<head>` section of our custom pages:

```
<link id="inlinecss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/yabq9wt8ttx4gte/test-jobboard.css?raw=1">
```

Now suddently we get errors and the stylesheet is no longer loaded for any of our solutions - this happended within the last few hours.

Chrome gives this warning:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/plain:
>   "https://uced539bdf7f835b3f3ff7fce14b.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/inline/AIVHvXpfCtgYI0pUYbGPg6hYJpcX-FI037Fsqa8Wh-QIceP4m8kc3RUERfGJN713K8kuZYOwB_HnqxcRdtIKJunr2CYVwJ575zc-91CcPEg7fh75M4K_3aSgZZP3OXg7GuIAgPeQBh5AREzjk88qzyRXKeUdwSygOyjKDh86MLjMkjD0k9oPelgUdNZN0DMYnWI/file"

and this:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://uced539bdf7f835b3f3ff7fce14b.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/inline/AIVHvXpfCtgYI0pUYbGPg6hYJpcX-FI037Fsqa8Wh-QIceP4m8kc3RUERfGJN713K8kuZYOwB_HnqxcRdtIKJunr2CYVwJ575zc-91CcPEg7fh75M4K_3aSgZZP3OXg7GuIAgPeQBh5AREzjk88qzyRXKeUdwSygOyjKDh86MLjMkjD0k9oPelgUdNZN0DMYnWI/file
>   with MIME type text/plain. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

Did Dropbox change the way files are served overnight

I just noticed that if I write something like this it is working:

```
<link id="inlinecss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/yabq9wt8ttx4gte/test-jobboard.css">
```

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Linked-CSS-file-with-raw-1-does-not-load-anymore-but-images/m-p/279617#M16794 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised that you were able to access the css without the "dl." as it allows you to access the source of the file rather the dropbox page in the original URL. Check [this](https://docs.helpscout.net/article/92-stylesheet-dropbox)